# Can't cast GetTypes() to interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm scanning a particular namespace for types that implement an interface, and trying to return them as that interface rather than just Type, but i'm getting an InvalidCastException

```
IEnumerable<IGameScript> GetDemos()
{
    var results = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(
        x => x.IsClass 
        && x.Namespace == "MMOClass.CodeBase.Demos" 
        && x.Name.Contains("Demo") 
        && x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IGameScript))
        ).Select(x => x);

    return results.Cast<IGameScript>();
}
```

**Update in response to Reed's answer:**

```
IEnumerable<IGameScript> GetDemos()
{
    var results = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(
        x => x.IsClass 
        && x.Namespace == "MMOClass.CodeBase.Demos" 
        && x.Name.Contains("Demo") 
        && x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IGameScript))
        ).Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x) as IGameScript);

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your LINQ query returns a collection of *Types* (`IEnumerable<System.Type>`) which implement the interface, not a collection of objects of that type.

However, you're trying to return an `IEnumerable<IGameScript>`, which would be a list of *instances* of objects that implement that interface.  You'll need to construct instances in order to cast to the interface itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have default constructors, you can simple reform your Select LINQ call to something like this and actually get the instances of that type:

```
.Select(x => Activator.CreateInstance(x))
```